# Blood pressure data management with Dexie.js - how should the data be structured?

Tags: vuejs3, indexeddb, nuxtjs3, dexie

I'd like to practise Dexie and Nuxt and thought of a little app that collects blood pressure (BP) data.

The idea is:

- measure the BP 3x a day (morning, noon, evening)
- each time measure the BP 3x in a row (with maybe a minute rest in between)
- the data collected consists of these 5 fields: timestamp, high, low, sys, comment

Disclaimer: I am not really sure, if – in medical terms – this makes much sense, but this is for practicing dexie, not becoming a doctor or patient. :-)

My question is: How do I structure these data in dexie?

I was initially thinking of a field structure like this:

```
db.version(1).stores({
    bp: "&uuid, dateMonth, daySection, data"
})
```

where `daySection` is either one of "morning", "noon", or "evening", and `data` is a json object of this form:

```
1: {
    timestamp,
    high,
    low,
    sys,
    comment
},
2: {
    timestamp,
    high,
    low,
    sys,
    comment
},
3: {
    timestamp,
    high,
    low,
    sys,
    comment
}
```

But this structure creates a lot of redundant data (like the first field, `yearMonth`, and also the `day` field). Not only that it is redundant, it is also hard to query, when an update should be done to a specific datum. (I see myself writing many for-loops or many `yearMonth.find('day' => ...)`.

On the other hand I keep reading that redundant data is rather common in NoSQL. Not sure, if this is the case here, though.

So I wonder, if there is a better way to structure and query such data? Any advises/ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found a solution for this already, but since the question is still open, I'll give it a shot.

Firstly, in `bp: "&uuid, dateMonth, daySection, data"` you are defining the **indexes**, not the fields. You can have many more fields.

I would suggest to create one record per measurement, so every single measurement would have the following fields: `uuid, date, daySection, timestamp, high, low, sys, comment`, where `date` would be something simple, like "20240201". You decide if you really need the exact time. If not, I'd also remove timestamp.

I would remove the `data` index, leaving `bp: "&uuid, date, daySection"`

Then the Dexie magic comes in: If you're planning to query/update records based on the date and the section of the day, you just create a [Compound Index](https://dexie.org/docs/Compound-Index): `[date+daySection]`. Your query would the simply be:

```js
db.bp.where({date: 20240201, daySection: 'noon'}).first()
```

This will give you that one specific record, which you then can manipulate how you want.

You can use [where](https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.where()) with any of the indexes. To get all the measurements of a day, you just do:

```js
db.bp.where("date").equals(20240201).toArray()
```

And so forth...

So, the final definition would be something like this:

```js
db.version(1).stores({
    bp: "&uuid, date, daySection, [date+daySection]"
})
```

and the final data model: `uuid, date, daySection, high, low, sys, comment`

Check out the doc pages I linked, they have great examples. I hope this helps. If it came too late, hopefully it helps someone else looking for some feedback.